# Exit pop up with registration form

Tags: forms, 6

I want to have anonymous users to have a pop up displayed after they visit first page and moving to second page. The pop up should have a Name and email and after submission user gets registered to our website. I'm confused which existing module can achieve it. I tried using [popup module](https://www.drupal.org/project/popup).  Or do I have to custom code to achieve it?

Comment: Did you tried creating your custom model (hardcoding) in your template php page? And why are you still using drupal 6?

Comment: No, I haven't tried any model in my template file. The client is using a drupal 6 site , which has some complex features hence he is taking time to upgrade to drupal 7. I want to know if any modules available even if it is for drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a module, try [Splashify](https://www.drupal.org/project/splashify). Splashify is although not available for Drupal 6. [Tinybox](https://www.drupal.org/project/tinybox) can help too but I haven't tried it myself.

You can also create this yourself, simplest way would be to change your front-page in configuration in toolbar, create that page, in drupal template, write something like this:

```
<?php
if (drupal_is_front_page()) {
    ?>
/*Your Splash Screen Code*/
<?php
    }
?>
```

Your Splash Screen Code can be a simple HTML Model, see this [Simple Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp).

Answer (score 0):

For drupal 8 users, Check this module https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_popup_blocks.

Description: Turn any blocks, forms or anything with CSS selectors into popup.

Triggering Methods: Automatic, Manual and Before browser/tab close